# Android : Get String / Input from other Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, textinput

I have an audio recorder (activity_audio_record_test.xml // AudioRecordTest.java) which opens via an `onClick` from  another activity(addemployee.xml // AddEmployee.java)

On the addemployee I have a text input which is being used to capture the project refrence number.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/txtName"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:maxLength="5"
  android:digits="0123456789"
  android:singleLine="true"
  />
```

which in the Java relates to

```
txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
```

and

```
public void btnAddEmp_Click(View view)
{
    boolean ok=true;
    try
    {
        Spannable spn=txtAge.getText();
        String name=txtName.getText().toString();
        int age=Integer.valueOf(spn.toString());
        int deptID=Integer.valueOf((int)spinDept.getSelectedItemId());
        Employee emp=new Employee(name,age,deptID);

        dbHelper.AddEmployee(emp);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ok=false;
        CatchError(ex.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if(ok)
        {
            //NotifyEmpAdded();
            Alerts.ShowEmpAddedAlert(this);
            txtEmps.setText("Number of Inspections on Device "+String.valueOf(dbHelper.getEmployeeCount()));
        }
    }
}
```

by the way, I know that the project refrence is called name, i'll get around to changing that later.

Anyhow, I am writing these audio recordings to a DB and a BYTE BLOB (or at least I plan to and the same with the photos too https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/25412248?noredirect=1). I need to use this project ref/txtName/Name field as the unique ID for this? is it possible to "parse"? this over the the second activity?

Thanks in advance,

Henry

---

More specific details

Page one (activity AddEmployee.Java // addemplyee.xml) is used to type details, multiple text field etc... Page two (activity activity_audio_record_test.xml // AudioRecordTest.java) is called by an onClick to open the second activity, record and save audio notes before returning to the main activity to finish entering the details. There is an input field (project ref/txtName/Name) on the main activity, which must be used as an identifier for the audio notes, to tie them in with the project. How can I get the user inputed ID from, the main activity over to the second activity...so that I am able to use it as a value for an input into the DB?

Hope this helps...

Comment: Could You be more specific? The problem is in reading data from db, isn't? Also, dbHelper might be useful, if the issue related to db structure.

Comment: more details added above, thanks...

Comment: Have You tried to put necessary data to start intent for second activity (using Intent.putExtra(String name, Bundle value)) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this counts as an answer as such, so I am not going to accept it, however it is a solution.

I am moving all the intents into one activity. Therefore, there is no need to pass the data through to my second activity. Instead, I can just pull the same txtName field to write my data table, image table and audio notes table in one hit.

Simple outside(but not so outside) of the box solution to the problem at hand... Window, white board pen and a flow chart diagram of data transfer helped me here...